# Update part of nested array of objects in a parent object using mongoose findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is a part of a `mongoose` model

```
const mandateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    customer: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    tariffs: {
        gas: {
            product_name: {
                type: String
            },
            code: {
                type: String
            },
            default_coefficients: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            assigned_eans: [{
                eanID: {
                    type: String,
                    ref: Ean,
                },
                status: {
                    type: String,
                    required: false
                },
                start_date: {
                    type: Number,
                },
                end_date: {
                    type: Number,
                },
                segment: {
                    type: String,
                    enum: ['b2c', 'soho', 'b2b', 'corporate', 'industry', 'direction']
                },
                stop_reason: {
                    type: String
                },
                stop_note: {
                    type: String
                },
            }]
        },
        electricity: {
            product_name: {
                type: String
            },
            code: {
                type: String
            },
            default_coefficients: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            assigned_eans: [{
                eanID: {
                    type: String,
                    ref: Ean,
                },
                start_date: {
                    type: Number,
                },
                end_date: {
                    type: Number,
                },
                segment: {
                    type: String,
                    enum: ['b2c', 'soho', 'b2b', 'corporate', 'industry', 'direction']
                },
                stop_reason: {
                    type: String
                },
                stop_note: {
                    type: String
                },
            }]
        }
    },
    start_date: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: false
    },
    end_date: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: false
    },
    end_from_ip: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    stop_reason: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    stop_reason_description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    sign_date: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    sign_token: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    sign_from_ip: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
```

Based on a given `_id` and `eanID` I'm looking for a way to update the object which matches the `eanID` with a new `status`, `end_date`, `stop_reason` and optional a `stop_note` without losing the already filled in `start_date` and `eanID`.

The start was pretty easy `EnergyMandate.findByIdAndUpdate(energyMandateId`.
But for the update part I don't know how I can find the matching object. I have checked other solutions on Stackoverflow but in my example there is first the split between tariffs.gas and tariffs.electricity and then the search for a matching eanID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like this:

```js
EnergyMandate.findByIdAndUpdate(energyMandateId,
{
  $set: {
    "tariffs.gas.assigned_eans.$[elem].status": yourNewStatus,
    "tariffs.gas.assigned_eans.$[elem].end_date": yourNewEndDate,
    "tariffs.gas.assigned_eans.$[elem].stop_reason": yourNewStopReason,
    "tariffs.gas.assigned_eans.$[elem].stop_note": yourNewStopNote
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.eanID": yourEanId
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RJ5E7txwJ9c)

Comment: Your example is working, but `tariffs` has two child objects (`gas` and `electricity`). How would it be possible to extend the current code to work for both gas and electricity? I attempted to add another arrayFilter, but since tariffs is not an array but an object, this approach did not work.

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ppp8m9HfBPk) what are you looking for?